# Java: Read from console

Tags: java, console

I'm don't know how to read from the console in Java.
If it's possible I want to do it using a scanner.
This is what i tried while learning Java.

```
package Scanners;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleScanner {


    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(input.equals("Hello"))
            System.out.println("You typed in: Hello ");
        if(input.equals("Good Bye"))
            System.out.println("You typed in: Good Bye");
        else{
            System.out.println("You typed in: " + input);
        }


    }

}
```

It give's me this error:

> You typed in:
>   java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match
>   valid=false][need input=false][source
>   closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=.][decimal
>   separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive
>   suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

If there is a better way to read from the console then please post it.
- Thanks

Comment: Please read a tutorial on IO, [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) maybe.

Comment: Also, that is not an error.

Comment: `Scanner#nextLine()` .. Example : `String s = input.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to print the Scanner itself. You want to call the various Scanner functions to get the input. Have a look at the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and the [Scanner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) (which are the first and second results for googling "Java Scanner") for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> package Scanners;
>
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class ConsoleScanner {
>
> ```
> static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates the scanner
>
> public static void main(String[] args){
>
>     String input = scanner.NextLine();  //Sets the string input equal to whatever the user types next
>
>     if(input.equals("Hello"))
>         System.out.println("You typed in: Hello ");
>     if(input.equals("Good Bye"))
>         System.out.println("You typed in: Good Bye");
>     else{
>         System.out.println("You typed in: " + input);
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

My friend you have to use

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scanner.next();
```

This method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

Comment: @Nicken99, My friend if this works for please right click on the answer, so it will be helpful for others

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
class ScannerDemo{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  

   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  

   System.out.println("Enter your age");  
   int age=sc.nextInt();  

   System.out.println("age:"+age);  

 }  
}
```